# Eslint to catch potential null pointer inside React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have a functional component in react like so (very reduced example):

```
const MyComponent = ({ something }) => {
  const output = format(something.value)

  return <p>{output}</p>
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  something: PropTypes.shape({
    value: PropTypes.string
  }
}
```

In this case, it would be allowed, as defined by PropTypes, for this component to be created without the `something` prop. If this happens the component will blow up with a TypeError due to trying to access a property (`value`) on undefined (`something`).

Given that this is possible to analyse from just the PropType (not required) and the code (no null check) I am wondering if there's a rule for eslint that can pick this up *before* runtime, so that it can be fixed with either a null check or optional chaining (or the prop being made more strict)?

I have searched online for what I think would be related keywords but tend to just find other eslint rules relating to nulls, but not for this particular case.

Here's a [repository that can demonstrate the issue in full](https://github.com/M1ke/react-prop-null-pointer-example)

To avoid having to click through, in case there's an obvious answer, here's the `.eslintrc` file from the project:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jquery": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "modules": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2019,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": ["prettier", "react", "react-hooks"],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "plugin:react-hooks/recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": "warn",
        "react/jsx-no-target-blank": "off",
        "no-prototype-builtins": "off",
        "react/display-name": "off",
        "react/no-array-index-key": "warn",
        "no-case-declarations": "off"
    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
    }
}
```